# What is the max sampling rate for scipy.io.wavfile.write command?

Tags: python, audio, scipy, wav

As I checked, usually it is 44100 Hz, but I am wondering for my own purposes can it be 490 KHz? Didn't notice any information about that in documentation. I successfully made a wavfile with 48000 Hz, but it's nearly the same that 44100.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.io import wavfile

# User input
duration=5.0
toneFrequency_left=500 #Hz (20,000 Hz max value)
toneFrequency_right=1200 #Hz (20,000 Hz max value)

# Constants
samplingFrequency=495000

# Generate Tones
time_x=np.arange(0, duration, 1.0/float(samplingFrequency))
toneLeft_y=np.cos(2.0 * np.pi * toneFrequency_left * time_x)
toneRight_y=np.cos(2.0 * np.pi * toneFrequency_right * time_x)

# A 2D array where the left and right tones are contained in their respective rows
tone_y_stereo=np.vstack((toneLeft_y, toneRight_y))

# Reshape 2D array so that the left and right tones are contained in their respective columns
tone_y_stereo=tone_y_stereo.transpose()

# Produce an audio file that contains stereo sound
wavfile.write('stereoAudio.wav', samplingFrequency, tone_y_stereo)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. **What happens** if you try specifying the sampling rate that you want? How is that different from what you want to happen? More importantly, what **problem do you hope to solve** by creating a wav file with an exceptionally high sampling rate? *What should happen* when trying to play it, if the hardware doesn't support that sampling rate? Are you *actually trying to create audio*, or do you just need to save high-frequency sample data in a raw format?

Comment: Does https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV answer your question?

Comment: I wrote a small code for monochrome wave and it looks like it still generates 44 KHz wavfile even if I increased sampling rate manually to 490 KHz

Comment: "looks like it still generates 44 KHz wavfile" What code did you use, and *how did you verify* that result? For example, did you check the file size?

Comment: I want to play stereo file through headphones to generate pictures in oscilloscope like here https://youtu.be/4gibcRfp4zA, 44 KHz is not enouph even for 10 FPS

Comment: added code to my question. I copied it somewhere and as I thought if I increase sampling rate, noise frequency should also increase

Comment: I can't understand. Why does playing the file through headphones help with creating the oscilloscope picture? Wouldn't you want to feed the signal directly to the oscilloscope? Your speakers will definitely not accurately reproduce details of the input at 490 KHz. It also isn't at all clear to me how there is any "frame rate" to speak of with an oscilloscope, how you're measuring that frame rate, or why it would have anything to do with the signal sampling frequency.

Comment: I think you really have an *audio engineering* question underlying this, not a question about how to write the code. The WAV format represents frequencies as a 32-bit integer, so its metadata will represent frequencies up to about 4.3 GHz; and I'm unaware of Scipy imposing any other limits

Comment: Yes, I want to directly feed stereo signal to XY connector (each channel for each axis) and if I want to play video I have to paint every shot very fast. But if I limit time for the shot (10 FPS for ex) it could be not enough time to paint all picture (600*900 pixels), it means I need at least 2*10^(-7 second) time interval in sampling rate

Comment: ok, if there is not program limits it's all I wanted to know

Comment: When I try your code, I get the expected output. I can open the resulting audio file in an audio editing program and verify that the sampling rate is 495000 Hz and it plays normally. The file size is also exactly as I'd expect. This question has nothing to do with programming and everything to do with the **hardware** that you want to use the audio file with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there isn't a max value for the Hz you can write, I've definitely written to files with higher rates, up to 96 kHz. That's about as high quality it gets as far as I've seen with audio files. Most audio files are 8 kHz I think, 44.1 and 48 are also common. 49 kHz is not as commonly seen.

Edit: 490 is not commonly seen. Also I just worked with a file at 192 kHz today

Comment: OP said 490, not 49.